# Assigning activity to an entire group without doing the search beforehand?

Tags: activities, groups, search, core

What would be the easiest way to a get the Record Activity screen prefilled with the contacts from a group without having to search before hand?

I wanted to add a link to the menu which would give me the Record Activity screen prefilled with all the contacts in a certain group. How would I go about doing this? Should I be looking into custom searches/ custom profiles/ do I do the javascript, do I play with search result templates and url parameters?

Or is there an easier way to achieve what I want?
I am trying to determine whether this could be done easily enough to justify the shortening of the process of assigning activities to groups.

Comment: there has been quite a lot of discussion about using arguments. this seems to have stalled https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12455 but perhaps it has already been done so you could add the group_id in to the Adv Search URL. Sorry i can't find a definite solution

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I think I will just create an extension with custom /CRM/Activity/Form/Activity.php form which receives the gid parameter.